# Enviando Post para o PHP

Tags: php, formulário, post

Eu tenho uma pagina que recebe um post com um array maior que 1000, esse array era "pequeno" e funcionava bem, porém eu percebi recentemente que parte do conteúdo enviado agora não está chegando do  outro lado, existe alguma restrição para a quantidade de dados enviado no Post para o PHP?

Comment: Existe a configuração `post_max_size`, mas se os dados excedessem esse tamanho as variáveis superglobais `$_POST` e `$_FILES` ficariam vazias, não parcialmente preenchidas como você relatou. Então é possível que o problema seja outro. Já verificou os arquivos de log do seu servidor?

Comment: obrigado, era esse post_max_size mesmo, resolveu aqui, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode ser devido ao `post_max_size`.

Existem dois locais diferentes que você pode configurar isso:

**php.ini**

```
post_max_size=20M
upload_max_filesize=20M
```

**.htaccess / httpd.conf / virtualhost include**

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

Qual você deverá usar depende de qual você possui acesso.

`.htaccess` não requer o restart do servidor, mas `php.ini` e outras configurações de apache sim

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size